# Passing salt minion id to Jenkins pipeline from a flat file

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, salt-stack

I'm looking for some ideas there. I have a set of Jenkins pipeline jobs. The Target machine /Minion name is passed as a parameter into the job and the jobs are running fine. I have been asked to drive it through a file. .i.e. all the minion ids or target machine is listed in a flat file and I want Jenkins to pick machine names in the loop and execute the pipeline. The pipeline runs salt state files in the background. Any idea, how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the file `minions.txt` containing list of minions, e.g.

```
minion_01
minion_02
minion_03
```

`salt` can target the minions by list when you use `-L`/`--list` option.

You can call e.g. `test.ping` on these minions by the following command:

```
salt --list `awk -vORS=, '{ print $1 }' minions.txt | sed 's/,$/\n/'` test.ping
```

`ORS` is Output Record Separator in `awk` and you ask `awk` to print the file line by line but output the lines using `,` as separator. `sed` removes the last entry.

Finally, you can wrap it in Jenkins with `sh """ ... """`

Comment: many thanks. I really appreciate your suggestion. However, i forgot to mention i need to create new jobs each to the targeted minion. Below is my working solution:            for minionid in `cat /home/jenkins/jenkins-data/minionid.txt`

do

echo "process started for ${minionid}"

java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://XXXXXXXX:8080/ copy-job Cloud-gating/bulk-upload-job cloud-gating/bulk-upload-job-${minionid}

java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://XXXXXXXXX:8080/ build Cloud-gating/bulk-upload-job-${minionid} -p minionID=${minionid} -s -v

echo "process complete for ${minionid}"

done

Comment: when i execute the cmd from Jenkins, i get the below error. Any idea?WorkflowScript: 13: illegal string body character after dollar sign;
   solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 13, column 19.
                     sh """salt -L  `awk -vORS=, '{ print \$1 }' /srv/salt/TMjenkins/minions.txt | sed 's/,$/\n/'` test.ping """"